# How to merge two csv files by keeping the duplicate column name in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I  have "a.csv" and "b.csv" . I tried to merge them with below commands

```
cd c:/users/mine/test 
Get-Content   a.csv, b.csv |  Select-Object -Unique | Set-Content -Encoding ASCII joined.csv
```

But I got Output file like b.csv added by end of the row of  a.csv. I wanted add  by end of the column of a.csv then b.csv columns should begin
    Note:- I cant install Join-Object module in my server.

```
Vm     Resource    SID
mnvb    vclkn     vxjcb
vjc.v   vnxc,m    bvkxncb

Vm      123     456     789
b      apple    banana  orange 
v      lemon    onion   tomato
```

My expected output should be like below. Without changing the order and keeping Vm column name without over writing

```
Vm     Resource    SID   Vm   123      456  789
mnvb    vclkn   vxjcb    b   apple    banana  orange 
vjc.v   vnxc,m  bvkxncb  v   lemon    onion   tomato
```

Comment: I cant install Join-Object module in my server

Comment: Duplicate column names is a bad thing in csv (or any type of structured data). Why would you want that??

Comment: @iRon It worked...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [`Join-Object`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join) is based on **script** rather than a **module**, this means that you might first "install" (download) it on another machine and that just copy/paste it (or the contents) to your server. You might also download it from the [project site](https://github.com/iRon7/Join-Object) and [dot-source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) the script: `. .\Join-Object.ps1`.
See also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026).

**Specific to your question:**
As @Theo commented "*Duplicate column names is a bad thing in csv*", especially in PowerShell where a `ConvertFrom-Csv` cmdlet will  cause an error on such a csv file.
The [`Join-Object`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join) script has although a possibility to join object based on the row index by simply omitting the `-On` parameter. In that case it will put columns that exist on both sides in an array by default:

```
Import-Csv a.csv | Join-Object (Import-Csv b.csv) | Format-Table

Vm         Resource SID     123   456    789
--         -------- ---     ---   ---    ---
{mnvb, b}  vclkn    vxjcb   apple banana orange
{vjc.v, v} vnxc,m   bvkxncb lemon onion  tomato
```

By using the `-Discern` parameter, `Join-Object` spits the duplicate values over two columns using the discern values as prefixes:

```
Import-Csv a.csv | Join-Object (Import-Csv b.csv) -Discern a,b | Format-Table

aVm   Resource SID     bVm 123   456    789
---   -------- ---     --- ---   ---    ---
mnvb  vclkn    vxjcb   b   apple banana orange
vjc.v vnxc,m   bvkxncb v   lemon onion  tomato
```