# Append 2 pscustomobjects into 1

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, psobject, pscustomobject

[image]

I am new to powershell.
I have 2 pscustomobjects in powershell script. I want to bring them together as one and output into csv.

The problem is there is no key column to match in both, just want to append them together.
I was able to use the following code but it does not show the data correctly. Any Suggestions? (sample attached)

```
$result=[pscustomobject]($a+$b)
```

Comment: Could you share a simple example of `$a` and `$b` and how would expect `$result` to look like?

Comment: If values are numbers : $result=[pscustomobject]([int]$a+[int]$b)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I attached the sample to question.

Comment: @jdweng values are mostly string.

Comment: Then cast to string instead of int.

Comment: Using this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [How to merge two csv files by keeping the duplicate column name in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61609920/1701026) and [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)): `$Result = $a |Join $b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you're looking to do is merge the [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_properties?view=powershell-7.3) from both objects into one.

You can access the properties and property values of an object via the [intrinsic member `PSObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members?view=powershell-7.2#psobject), in this case you would need to enumerate all properties from both objects (`$a` and `$b`) and put them together into an [ordered dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2#creating-ordered-dictionaries) and lastly cast [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.3) to it to get a new *merged* object as a result. This function can simplify that process for you.

```bash
function Merge-PSCustomObject {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [Object] $LeftObject,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [Object] $RigthObject
    )

    end {
        $result = [ordered]@{}
        foreach($property in @($LeftObject.PSObject.Properties; $RigthObject.PSObject.Properties)) {
            $result[$property.Name] = $property.Value
        }
        [pscustomobject] $result
    }
}

$a = [pscustomobject]@{ foo = 'hello' }
$b = [pscustomobject]@{ bar = 'world'; baz = 123 }

Merge-PSCustomObject -LeftObject $a -RigthObject $b
```

---

If you have an array of objects in both sides, **assuming both arrays have the same count of objects**, you can use a [`for` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-7.3) to merge each object in both arrays, for example:

```bash
$a = [pscustomobject]@{ foo = 'hello' }
$b = [pscustomobject]@{ bar = 'world'; baz = 123 }

$arr1 = 0..3 | ForEach-Object { $a }
$arr2 = 0..3 | ForEach-Object { $b }

$result = for($i = 0; $i -lt $arr1.Count; $i++) {
    Merge-PSCustomObject $arr1[$i] $arr2[$i]
}
```

Comment: I got following output instead of table:
Count Length LongLength Rank SyncRoot IsReadOnly IsFixedSize IsSynchronized
12 12 12 1 System.Object[] FALSE TRUE FALSE

Comment: @Harry this function works for single objects on both sides it's not meant to merge arrays of objects

Comment: @Harry see the update, that should work for merging both arrays assuming they have the same count of objects.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Instead of using
 $arr1 = 0..3 | ForEach-Object { $a }
I sis a count on first array object and then used it. Works perfect! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

See if following works :

```
for($i = 0; $i -lt $a.Count; $i++)
{
   $a[$i] | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Sample3 -NotePropertyValue $b[$i].Sample3
}
```

Comment: I did try this method but for some reason sample3 table was not showing up at all. I tried the function from @Santiago Squarzon and it worked. Thank you for the help!